# Random generation in heavily nested loops

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, multidimensional-array

I have a little game I've been making for a school project, and it has worked up until now.

I used a very messy nested list system for multiple screens, each with a  2D array for objects on screen. These 2D "level" arrays are also arranged in their own 2D array, which makes up the "world". The strings correspond to an object tile, which is drawn using pygame.

**My problem is that every `level` array is the same in the `world array`, and I can't understand why that is.**

```
 def generate_world(load):
    # This bit not important
    if load is True:
        in_array()
    # This is
    else:
        for world_y in Game_world.game_array:
            for world_x in world_y:
                generate_clutter(world_x)

    print Game_world.game_array
    out_array()
    # Current_level.array = Level.new_level_array


def generate_clutter(world_x):
    for level_y in world_x:
        for level_x, _ in enumerate(level_y):

            ### GENERATE CLUTTER ###
            i = randrange(1, 24)
            if i == 19 or i == 20:
                level_y[level_x] = "g1"
            elif i == 21 or i == 22:
                level_y[level_x] = "g2"
            elif i == 23:
                level_y[level_x] = "c1"
            else:
                level_y[level_x] = "-"
```

I'm sure it's something simple I'm overlooking, but to me it seems the random generation should be carried out for every single list item individually, so I can't understand the duplication.

I know quadruple nested lists aren't pretty, but I think I'm in too deep to make any serious changes now.

EDIT:

This is the gist of how the lists/arrays are initially created. Their size doesn't ever change, existing strings are just replaced.

```
class World:

    def __init__(self, name, load):
        if load is False:
            n = [["-" for x in range(20)]for x in range(15)]

            self.game_array = [[n, n, n, n, n, n, n],
                              [n, n, n, n, n, n, n],
                              [n, n, n, n, n, n, n]]
```

Comment: You need to show how Game_world.game_array is populated: putting the same object in multiple list places is a common mistake. For example, Game_world.game_array=[[make_empty_level()]*50]*50 would create a list of lists with 2500 references to the same level object.

Comment: What do you mean "how it is populated?"

Each "world" takes this shape:
                             [[n, n, n, n, n, n, n],
                              [n, n, n, n, n, n, n],
                              [n, n, n, n, n, n, n]]
(i.e. a 7 * 3 grid)

and each n is a 20 * 15 grid.
Is that what you meant?

Comment: Did you create an empty array initially? If so, how? Lorenzo is almost certainly right. try the following in an interpreter: `l=[[1]*2]*2;l;l[0][0]=2;l`

Comment: yes the arrays are initially just filled with "-" which is my marker for an empty space. I'm not that kind of learner, sorry, I don't really get what that shows me

Comment: @Tom, did you try that? If so what did you see? What did you expect to see?

Comment: Ah yes I understand it now, sorry It's late and I wasn't making the connection mentally :S yes that and kdopen's answers helped, but I am still stuck as to how to implement it in my situation. I initialized the lists in kdopen's new way, but nothing changed. What else should I change? Perhaps I am misinterpreting this.

Comment: You now have an array containing multiple references to the same instance of `n`. Changing any one of them will change all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, everything is an object - even integer values. How you initialize an 'empty' array can have some surprising results.

Consider this initialization:

```
>>> l=[[1]*2]*2
>>> l
[[1, 1], [1, 1]]
```

You appear to have created a 2x2 matrix with each cell containing the value `1`. In fact, you have created a list of two lists (each containing `[1,1]`). Deeper still, you have created a list of two references to a single list `[1,1]`.

The results of this can be seen if you now modify one of the cells

```
>>> l[0][0]=2
>>> l
[[2, 1], [2, 1]]
>>>
```

Notice that both `l[0][0]` and `l[1][0]` were modified.

To avoid this effect, you need to jump through some hoops

```
>>> l2 = [[1 for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(2)]
>>> l2
[[1, 1], [1, 1]]
>>> l2[0][0]=2
>>> l2
[[2, 1], [1, 1]]
>>>
```

If you used the former approach to initialize `Game_world.game_array` every assignment to `level_y[level_x]` will be modifying multiple cells in your array.

Just as an additional comment, your `generate_clutter` function can be simplified slightly using a `dict`

```
def generate_clutter(world_x):
    clutter_map = {19:"g1", 20:"g1", 21:"g2", 22:"g2", 23:"c1"}
    for level_y in world_x:
        for level_x, _ in enumerate(level_y):
            level_y[level_x] = clutter_map.get(randrange(1,24),'-')
```

This separates the logic of selecting the clutter representation from the actual mapping of values and will be much easier to expand and maintain.

Looking at your edit, the initialization needs to be something like:

```
self.game_array = [
                   [
                    [
                     ["-" for x in range(20)]
                     for x in range(15)
                    ]
                    for x in range(7)
                   ]
                   for x in range(3)
                  ]
```

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, so just initializing the lists by using "for _ in range(x)" fixes it?

Comment: You really need to mess around in the interpreter and get to understand it. Without seeing how you initialized the array, we are only guessing based on our own experience. I'd also suggest installing `ipython` to use as your interactive shell as it is much more friendly